# My process is mapping to a PCI memory hole, why?

Tags: c, memory, ubuntu, kernel, pci

I modified my kernel and walked the page table myself to get the physical address of one process's code section. I passed `(current->mm)->start_code` as the parameter to my function. The code for said function is listed below:

```
 unsigned long user_va_to_pa(unsigned long v) {

 pgd_t *pgd = pgd_offset(current->mm, v);
 printk("process id is %d\n",current->pid); 

 if (!pgd_none(*pgd)) {
    pud_t *pud = pud_offset(pgd, v);
    if (!pud_none(*pud)) {
        pmd_t *pmd = pmd_offset(pud, v);
        if (!pmd_none(*pmd)) {
            pte_t *pte;
            pte = pte_offset_map(pmd, v);
            if (pte_present(*pte)){
               unsigned long pa=pte_val(*pte) & PTE_PFN_MASK;
               printk(KERN_ALERT "pte value is (in vatopa) %lx\n", pte_val(*pte));
               pte_unmap(pte);
               return pa;   //return the real physical address(page aligned)           
            }
            else {
                printk(KERN_ALERT "cannot find pte\n");
            }

        }
        else{
            printk(KERN_ALERT "cannot find pmd\n");

        }
    }
    else {

        printk(KERN_ALERT "cannot find pud\n");
    }
 }
 else {
    printk(KERN_ALERT "cannot find PGD\n");         
 }
return 1;
}
```

However, it seems that very frequently the physical address is in a PCI memory hole. I called my function as a syscall from a user application. Note that my function can printout the address like so:

```
pte value is (in vatopa) efe2d025
```

Then I opened **iomem** by `$ cat /proc/iomem`.

I could see (show part):

```
   20000000-201fffff : reserved
20200000-40003fff : System RAM
40004000-40004fff : reserved
40005000-ced2ffff : System RAM
ced30000-dae9efff : reserved
dae9f000-daf9efff : ACPI Non-volatile Storage
daf9f000-daffefff : ACPI Tables
dafff000-df9fffff : reserved
dfa00000-febfffff : PCI Bus 0000:00
  e0000000-efffffff : 0000:00:02.0
  f0000000-f03fffff : 0000:00:02.0
  f0400000-f0bfffff : PCI Bus 0000:02
  f0c00000-f13fffff : PCI Bus 0000:04
  f1400000-f1bfffff : PCI Bus 0000:04
  f1c00000-f1cfffff : PCI Bus 0000:03
    f1c00000-f1c01fff : 0000:03:00.0
```

You can see that the address `efxxxxxx` is totally in the PCI memory hole. However, it is supposed to be residing in system RAM, right?

This has made me unable to reserve a page attribute for that page since it's in a memory hole which has another attribute. It is very weird.

As for my system, I use a 32 bit 12.04 Ubuntu kernel on an Intel i5 Core machine with 8GB of memory.

Comment: I figure out something. I use unsigned long (32bit) to get all the address. However, a PAE enabled kernel use 64bit in PTE and PDE right? So I need to use unsigned long long or something to make it correct. I will try it this afternoon